# License issue of Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: licensing, gpl, apache-license

If I use Spring Data Neo4j to develop a software, and I want to publish it for commercial use with charging, does there exist any license issue?

I survey many posts about the license issue of Neo4j and Spring Data Neo4j. It seems Neo4j has two versions, community and enterprise, respectively. The Community version is GPL-3.0, and the enterprise version is AGPL-3.0. Spring Data Neo4j is Apache License-2.0.

The role of spring data neo4j in my software:

1.It is only part of my software to deal with storing relationship and searching data.

2.I will combine it with MongoDB or DB2.

Comment: Can you clarify under which license Spring Data Neo4j is distributed and what relation your software would have with Spring Data Neo4j (uses it, modifies it, etc.).